# Is there any way to fix this crack in my laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, acer-aspire, laptop-repair

I have an Acer Aspire5250 that I've had for almost a year. Recently, it got a crack above one of the USB ports. Is there any cost effective way to repair this or is this something I'm just going to have to live with?

[image: Laptop Crack]

Comment: Its plastic, there isn't much you can do about it, you will have to live with it.  I would clean your keyboard, that thing is filthy, no offense.

Comment: Haha, no offense taken. Yes, some compressed air may be needed.

Comment: Its the back panel of LCD right?

Comment: @avirk No, it's the lower right portion below the keyboard.

Comment: I have only idea in my mind just melt down some black plastic and stick it carefully on it. I have done it on my laptop's LCD back panel. Otherwise the crack will  spread more.

Comment: It can be glued.  Take it to a hobby shop and ask them to give you the best glue for the task.  Then maybe go to a hardware store and pick up a small bar clamp to hold it together while the glue sets.  Probably you'll want to glue a piece of sheet plastic over the area -- maybe some thin sheet acrylic.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Glue would work, would at the very least, prevent it from getting worst.  Figured he means actually "repair" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where there is a will there is a way!

[image]

- Drill a small hole (1/8th inch) [at the very end of the crack](http://www.plasticgenius.com/2009/03/repairing-crack-in-plexiglass.html) to prevent further expansion of the crack, then fill the crack with your favorite high quality epoxy mix and let dry for 24-48 hours, grind/trim/carve/sand it and touch up paint to match, done.

Comment: Epoxy, exactly what I was going to suggest. Good old quick-dry Araldite is my preferred mix.

Comment: @MarkHenderson good ol epoxy! There is a new flexible epoxy out, not cheap but awesome, [G-Flex](http://www.westsystem.com/ss/g-flex-epoxy/)